# How to host JSP pages on external web server for more dynamic editing using Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I would like to be able to deploy and manage a set of jsp files outside of the application and the server.  We have a pain in the ... process for deploying our projects and we would like to be able to edit or create JSPs without redeploying the web app.

We are using Spring MVC 3 and I'd think you could use some custom `URLViewResolver` if that one can't do it itself...

The controller could then be configured in the database or something for various states picking which jsp to display.

Comment: If it is just for web development, what about just creating a network share to your WebContent folder and dropping the JSP pages in there when they are changed. Tomcat should pick up the new JSP next time its read without needing a web app redeploy.

Answer (score 0):

Rather change your development environment deployment process. You can:

- use the capabilities of your IDE to deploy the project on the container (but I assume this will be hard for complex builds)
- use [FileSync](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/filesync/index.html) (if using eclipse) and configure it to send modified jsps to the servlet container when they are changed

Both of these assume that you are running a servlet container locally.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I should add we don't have access to the file system from our corporate Websphere.  That probably made it Mt Everest.  Thanks!